# Paypal Rest API on Symfony

Tags: php, rest, paypal, payment-gateway, symfony

I'm trying to embed the paypal Rest API on my symfony project, but it returns me an error and even the technical service couldn't tell me where the problem could come from...

The error returned is the following : "Attempted to load class "ApiContext" from namespace "PayPal\Rest". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

But I already have the right use statement and the api has already been loaded with composer.

Here is the whole code, if it can help...

```
<?php

namespace PlatformBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;

class PaypalController extends Controller
{
    private function paypalKeys()
    {
        return new ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(
                'mykey',
                'mykey'
            )
        );
    }

    public function chargeAction()
    {
        $this->paypalKeys();
        $price = 10;
        $total = $price;

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $item = new Item();
        $item->setName('transfer')
            ->setCurrency('eur')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice($price);

        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems([$item]);

        $details = new Details();
        $details->setShipping(0)
            ->setSubtotal($price);

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('eur')
            ->setTotal($total)
            ->setDetails($details);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription('Description')
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost/dublin/web/app_dev.php/admin')
            ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost/dublin/web/app_dev.php/cancel');

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

//        try {
        $payment->create($this->paypalKeys());
//        } catch (Exception $e) {
//            die($e);
//        }
//
//        return new Response('true');
//        echo $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
    }
}
```

thank you...

Annex :

Beginning of my ApiContext file

```
namespace PayPal\Rest;

use PayPal\Core\PayPalConfigManager;
use PayPal\Core\PayPalCredentialManager;

/**
 * Class ApiContext
 *
 * Call level parameters such as request id, credentials etc
 *
 * @package PayPal\Rest
 */
class ApiContext
{

    /**
     * Unique request id to be used for this call
     * The user can either generate one as per application
     * needs or let the SDK generate one
     *
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
private function paypalKeys()
    {
        return new \ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(
                'mykey',
                'mykey'
            )
        );
}
```

Try putting a "\" before calling the class and tell if it works.

You should also check if the namespace inside you ApiContext is ok. :)

Comment: It doesn't change anything :/

Comment: @FabulousCo can you show me the beginning of the ApiContext file? The namespace?

Comment: Yeah, I just added it in annex in the post :) thanks for helping

Comment: @FabulousCo can you also put the composer part where you added this api?

Comment: here it is : "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "1.3.*",

Comment: @FabulousCo Did you enabled the api in the AppKernel? See this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html

Comment: I tested by adding this : "new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext()," but it returned me a 500 error

Comment: And if you put `new PayPal\Rest\ApiContext()` ? Without the `\`in the beginning?

Comment: I tried it as well, and same error 500 :/
In dev mode in local it returns me this fatal error : "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PayPal\Rest\ApiContext::getName() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dublin/var/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2434"

Comment: @FabulousCo that is a different error. The class was found but not the method. You're executing the same code you put in your question? You didn't call there any `getName()`

Comment: It is executed in the bootstrap.php.cache file which comes from the framework (symfony). But I didn't every touch to that file, I don't even understand what it is for :/